# Unity3d not liking collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class chicken_for : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate () {

        if (collision.gameObject.Quad == collisionObject){
            Application.LoadLevel("SciFi Level");
        }
    }
}
```

I am attempting to when A person touches a quad, he goes to this sci-fi fortress. It however says the name 'collision' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Of course it doesn't. Where is `collision` defined? `collision` is the name of a variable which points to an instance of an object. You will need to have that variable defined somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're referencing a variable (`collision`) that doesn't exist. You've got a variable `collisionObject` that doesn't exist, too.

`collision` is typically the name of the argument to the [`OnCollisionEnter`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.OnCollisionEnter.html) method. Your code should probably be inside this method instead of `FixedUpdate`. I'm guessing that you've copied code from a tutorial somewhere but put it in the wrong method.

`collisionObject` on the other hand is harder to guess, but I expect that if your script is intended to be a component on the player object, then `collisionObject` should be your quad; if the script is on the quad then `collisionObject` should be the player.

Either way, you need to declare that variable - probably as a public field so that you can populate it from the inspector.

Comment: So your saying... void OnCollisionEnter () {

        if (collision.gameObject.Quad == collisionObject){
            Application.LoadLevel("SciFi Level");
        }
    }?

Comment: Read the link: the method has a parameter too. `void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) { ... }`  - that's one of your two undefined variables.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new function and make sure the player is tagged as player in the inspector. You also need to make sure that there is a collider on the quad that the player touches and a rigidbody component on the player.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class chicken_for : MonoBehaviour {

//This function will handle the collision on your object
void OnCollisionEnter (Collider col){
    if(col.gameobject.tag == "Player"){    //if colliding object if tagged player
        Application.LoadLevel("SciFi Level"); //load the sci-fi level
    }
}
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    }
}
```

This should get you roughly where you want to be!